# Problem Sending FormData to PHP together with string data

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I want to send the file data together with string data. I am able to send it from ajax to PHP. But in  PHP I can not get correct **string data** from $_POST[] This doesn´t work. I don´t know how to get the correct string.

I got only initial alphabet from a string. No specific product that I want.

**Here is ajax**

```
var action = "product1="+myProduct1+"&product2="+product2;
    var file_data = $('#myfile').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        form_data.append('action', action);

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "URL TO PHP",

data:form_data,

dataType: 'json',
contentType: false,
processData: false,
success: function(response){
//Do something
},
});
```

**PHP**

```
$data=$_POST['data'];
$action=$_POST['action'];

    $mydata = array("myStatus"=>"ok", "myMsg"=>$action['product1']);
     echo json_encode($mydata);
```

**UPDATE**

I found one solution :
javascript script:

```
var file_data = $('#myfile').prop('files')[0];
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file_data);
form_data.append('product1',my_product1);
form_data.append('product2',my_product2);
```

PHP code :

```
$data=$_POST['data'];
    $mydata = array("myStatus"=>"ok", "myMsg"=>$_POST['product2']);
     echo json_encode($mydata);
```

I am a bit satisfy with this. If someone has another solution would be nice. Because I have lots of string data in this code. If I do manual like this....will look stupid. Unless this is the only solution I can do.

Answer (score 0):

you may try like this,

```
var action = [
{
    product : "product1",           
},
{
    product : "product2"
}];

var file_data = $('#myfile').prop('files')[0];
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file_data);
form_data.append('action',  JSON.stringify(action));

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "URL TO PHP",

data:form_data,

dataType: 'json',
contentType: false,
processData: false,
success: function(response){
//Do something
},
});
```

and in php side,

```
$data = json_decode($post,true);
//print_r($data);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
     echo $value['product'];echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)

I have tried your code, but it doesn´t work the way I want.
I want to to have each data to be used to insert into database.

Can you tell me how to do in PHP that way ?

Comment: hi @Masaru can you try with edited code

Comment: Hi, yes I have tried. It doesn´t work. I have updated my question above. I found the code is working. The output is corrrect. But I want another solution (If there is a nother solution).

Comment: Every answer should include an explanation. "Try like this" (code-only answers) miss a great opportunity to educate the asker and thousands of future researchers.

Comment: You say "I have lots of string data in this code. If I do manual like this....will look stupid". May you give 2 data examples from your real case so readers can understand your difficulty easily. And what's your issue with the given answer?

Comment: @Ersin Sorry for late reply. I just realized that I obsessed with ways to smarter code (more short and more effective) and forgot to see that sometimes there´s no differences between this. So sorry for this. My original code was: to send all data with a set of array like: data = "product1="+p1+"&product2="+p2; and so on... For  if in this array I have 20 products it will look so stupid for me to do like : form_data.append('product1',my_product1)++++++so on. So I was thinking if there are some  smart code to send my data array without append 1 by 1.  :)

Comment: @Ersin and  one more reason that I can not send like : data = "product1="+p1+"&product2="+p2;++++++so on. Because in PHP there is issue to use this data. This way will work only when I send normal ajax (no file) to PHP. That´s why I must use  form_data.append('product1',my_product1)++++++so on. And as I mentioned above that I obsessed with finding smarter code and forgot to see that´s no difference. Because Array on my original code is still long. No differnce, no shorter. :)

Comment: In order to avoid lots of strings, you may search repeating patterns in your strings and create dynamic variables just in time like. assume you get integer id list of your products. foreach id `$string[] = 'product' . $id` . Also you may need to use dynamic variables like `${$var}` to construct smarter codes.